Ubuntu Server 22.04 Installing Nvidia drivers for an older card
I'm trying to setup Nvidia drivers on my headless ubuntu server box for my GeForce 9800 GT but I'm obviously missing something and need assistance.
I've tried following this guide https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation but was stuck instantly as neither sudo ubuntu-drivers list --gpgpu or sudo ubuntu-drivers devices is returning any output.
Other guides https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/ suggested installing the nvidia-driver-550 nvidia-dkms-550 packages and rebooting, which I did without success.
My understanding is that I would need the matching kernel module (nvidia-kernel-common-550-server) as well as the correct driver version (nvidia-driver-550-server) which are both installed. I rebooted several times just to be sure without any luck so far.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G92 [GeForce 9800 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f4000000-f5ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: VESA VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=640,480


$ uname -r
5.15.0-113-generic

$ dkms status
nvidia-srv/550.90.07, 5.15.0-113-generic, x86_64: installed

$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GT] (rev a2)

$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-550-server:amd64        550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-550-server            550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64            390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                    amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-525:amd64            525.147.05-0ubuntu2.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package (transitional package)
rc  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64            535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-550:amd64            550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-550-server:amd64     550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-container-tools              1.15.0-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA container runtime library (command-line tools)
ii  libnvidia-container1:amd64             1.15.0-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA container runtime library
ii  libnvidia-decode-550-server:amd64      550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-550-server:amd64      550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-550-server:amd64       550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA Server Driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-550-server:amd64        550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-550-server:amd64          550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-390               390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                    amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-550               550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-550-server        550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-container-toolkit               1.15.0-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA Container toolkit
ii  nvidia-container-toolkit-base          1.15.0-1                                    amd64        NVIDIA Container Toolkit Base
rc  nvidia-dkms-390                        390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                    amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-535                        535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-550                        550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-550-server                 550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-550-server               550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-550-server-550.90.07   550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-390               390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                    amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-525               525.147.05-0ubuntu2.22.04.1                 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module (transitional package)
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-535               535.183.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                 amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-550               550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-550-server        550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-550-server        550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                           0.8.17.1                                    all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                        510.47.03-0ubuntu1                          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-550-server                550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA Server Driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                0.18.2                                      all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550-server   550.90.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               user@host 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           --------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: B450 AORUS M 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-113-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 24 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1277 (dpkg), 6 (flatpak), 5 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 (12) @ 3.200GHz 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Memory: 2875MiB / 15931MiB 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/                            
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+                             
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.



sudo apt purge every package with nvidia in its name. Then for your 16 year old card, pick the oldest Nvidia drivers offered (470?) with sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470  , reboot.  That should give you a running setup.

Thanks for the answer! Tried that. the oldest one is nvidia-driver-390 rebooted. None of the above outputs have changed except the dpkg -l and dkms status ofc.

If it is a headless server box, what would you do with the graphics card? Scientific computing with GPU?


would you do with the graphics card
transcoding, experimenting and also some scientific computing


I suspect there are conflicts with Nvidia drivers and Ubuntu kernel 5.15.0-113 on certain hardware.
For me, new install of Ubuntu > apt update/upgrade landed me on 5.15.0-113.
I'm personally working with the CUDA Toolkit. Tried to install CUDA and the Nvidia drivers. Every flavor caused boot freezing.
I noticed that CUDA Toolkit recommended the 6.5.0-27 kernel for Ubuntu 22.04 lts:
Boot into recovery mode and remove Nvidia drivers

Power on
Tap shift to get into Grub menu
Select Advanced options for Ubuntu
Boot via recovery mode
When the recovery menu appears, continue normal boot
sudo apt remove --purge *nvidia*
Reboot (make sure a normal boot works)

Install your new kernel flavor

sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-6.5.0-27-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic
Reboot (boot into new kernel)

Blacklist Nouveau driver (perhaps optional)

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
add line: blacklist nouveau
add line: options nouveau modeset=0

Install your Nvidia drivers
I was installing with CUDA Toolkit, so I used sudo apt-get install -y cuda-drivers, but you should be in the clear here to install your normal way.
After install, reboot and profit.

Nice and detailed answer. Thank you! Since it's a headless box that is out of my physical reach booting into recovery mode is not an option. But your solution should work without recovery mode too right? purging nvidia, rebooting, updating the kernel, blacklisting nouveau, installing drivers.
